# Problem deploying a Rails application to tomcat with warbler - undefined method 'getProperty'

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, tomcat5.5, warbler

I'm trying to deploy our app to a standalone tomcat 5.5 on hardy.

The resulting war file is unpacked (correctly as it seems) but won't load and gives me the following error:

```
Application initialization failed: undefined method `getProperty' for Java::JavaLang::System:Class
from file:/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/scaleup/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.4.jar!/jruby/rack/core_ext.rb:26
from file:/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/scaleup/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.4.jar!/jruby/rack/core_ext.rb:36:in `require'
from file:/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/scaleup/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.4.jar!/jruby/rack.rb:36
from file:/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/scaleup/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.4.jar!/jruby/rack.rb:8:in `require'
from file:/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/scaleup/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.4.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:8
from file:/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/scaleup/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.4.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:1:in `require'
from <script>:1
```

*Versions I use:*

```
JRuby 1.5.6
Ruby on Rails 3.0.3
JRuby-Rack 1.0.4
```

*On the server:*

```
tomcat 5.5.25
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!
Chris

Comment: Hmm... those are very new versions of JRuby and Rails, and a very old version of Tomcat. Can you upgrade to something newer, say Tomcat 7.0.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try apache-tomcat-6.0.29 instead. i have a lot of problems with tomcat5 too.

Comment: That you for the answers. Updating tomcat did not do any good on this topic so I switched to GlassFish and am now one step further (standing at the next - unrelated - error message).